# How can i use xpath or other method to get node content data from the rotator?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xpath, telerik, rotator

I create a `RadRotator` in run time and i bind on an `xml` file .

---

I don't know How to get the title from the `rotator` to set the text of my label .

---

```
lbl_date.Text = (lbl_date.NamingContainer as RadRotatorItem).DataItem
```

---

My `xml` part :

```
<news pnumber="1" id="1"><event_id>578</event_id><event_type_id>1</event_type_id><language_id>2</language_id><title>meeting</title></news>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i get it :

---

```
lbl_date.Text = XPathBinder.Eval((((lbl_date.NamingContainer as RadRotatorItem)).DataItem), "./title", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using an [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) to parse the XML:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

lbl_date.Text = xdoc.Root.Element("title").Value;
```

Note that the element name "title" used in the call .Element("title") is case sensitive.

Comment: I have already bind the control `rotator` on `xml` file i just need to know how to get the node .i can get it using this expression `<%# XPath("title")%>` .but i create the control in run time so i don't know how to access it.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Your binding the data in the .aspx page rather then the code-behind. OK, must admit I'm not sure how to solve your problem in that case, as I've never done that. Sorry.